# Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image][image]

I know how to solve for particular solution when the right hand side is polynomials, but how do I these kind of differential equations when the right hand side isn't a polynomial ?

Comment: Let the particular solution have the form $$\text{p(t)=Ae${}^{\wedge}$(-3t)}$$ for Q3b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is meant more as a comment than an answer.

Surprisingly, a lot of the time, solving ODE's quickly comes down to guesswork and experience. If you have an exponential $e^{-\lambda x}$ on the right hand side a good guess is $Ae^{-\lambda x}$. If $\lambda$ is a root of the characteristic equation however, you might want to try $xe^{-\lambda x}$ or higher powers of $x$ if needed.

If this seems very ishy washy to you, there do exist rigorous ways for solving ODE's without guess work. In fact, for linear second order ODEs, there is a closed form expression (well, as closed form as an integral gets) by using the method of [variation of parameters](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/VariationofParameters.aspx).

A good grasp of the latter method will allow you to solve quite a good range of second order ODEs (including the ones you posted) so is worth having a look at.

Comment: That helps!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

May be, to come back to the situation you know, make a change of variable.

For example, in the case of **(6)**, make $$y= e^{2t}z(t)$$ $$y'=e^{2 t} \left(z'(t)+2 z(t)\right)$$ $$y''=e^{2 t} \left(z''(t)+4 \left(z'(t)+z(t)\right)\right)$$ so the equation becomes $$e^{2 t} z''(t)=t^2e^{2 t}-e^{2 t}$$ Simplify and no more exponential (just polynomial terms in the rhs).